# Using Color Ramp Manager Plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, hillshade

I followed instructions mentioned [here](https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/create-great-looking-topographic-maps-in-qgis-2/) and installed the Color Ramp Manager by choosing install experimental plugins as well.

Now, when I go to Properties > Style > Single Band PsuedoColor and I choose New Color Ramp > Cpt-city > This empty box opens up.

[image]

How do I hillshade my region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current QGIS comes with `cpt-city` color ramps, that is probably the reason why the mentioned plugin is no longer maintained.

Uninstall the plugin. Then you will see the option to choose `cpt-city` sets when you click on New Color Ramp (as you have done).

The `sd-a`, recommended in the linked blog, is found in `Topography` group.